# detect the widest cell w/ jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a table with different values. First column contains labels. I need to get the width of the widest label. I assume I need some sort of a loop, but then what?

```
$("#myTable td:nth-child(1)").width();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Walk through each using `each()`, and check each's `width()`. I don't think there is an easier way

Comment: Wouldn't all first column td elements in a table be the same width?  Are you looking for the width of something inside the td elements?

Comment: This is where having a `.reduce()` function, as well as `.map()` would be useful in jQuery.

Comment: @jfriend00 Good point (I asked the same question below :) ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var w = 0;
$("#myTable tr td:first").each(function(){
    if($(this).width() > w){
        w = $(this).width();
    }
});
```

Comment: This is the widest column of all columns, not just the first column as the question asked.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you have one `<label>` element inside all `<td>` elements in the first column (since it makes no sense to compare the widths of the `<td>` elements themselves — within the same column they are equally wide (not considering `colspan != 1`)):

```
var widestLabel = 0;
$("#myTable td:nth-child(1) label").each(function() {
    widestLabel = Math.max(widestLabel, $(this).width());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var widest;
var widestWidth = 0;
$("#myTable td").each(function(t) {
    if($(this).width() > widestWidth){
        widest = $(this);
        widestWidth = $(this).width();
    }
});
//Now widest points to the widest element
```

Note I tracked the actual width separately from the widest element. An alternate solution without this method would be to initialize widest to a dummy element with width = 0 and just compare $(this).width() with widest.width()

**EDIT**: Or, alternately, now that I realize you wanted only the width and not the actual element, you could use this version:

```
var widestWidth = 0;
$("#myTable td").each(function(t) {
     widestWidth = Math.max(widestWidth, $(this).width());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var widestTdLabel=0;
$('#myTable td').each(function(index) { 
    if($(this).find('label').width()>widestTdLabel)
        widestTdLabel=$(this).find('label').width();
});
alert(' width of the widest label is:'+widestTdLabel);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work - it will go through each of the tds (in myTable) and find the widest:

```
var widest = 0;
$("#myTable tr td:first").each(function()
{
     widest = ($(this).width() > widest) : $(this).width() : widest;
});
```

alternatively:

```
var widest = 0;
$("#myTable tr td:first").each(function()
{
     if($(this).width() > widest){
         widest = $(this).width()
     }
});
```

Comment: This is the widest column of all columns, not just the first column as the question asked.