# Get widest element in a jQuery set

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Let's say I have a bunch of `<span>` elements with different text content.

How I can I get the widest `<span>`?

jQuery is fine. I only care about identifying the span, not the value of the width itself.

A similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246683/detect-the-widest-cell-w-jquery). But they only get the value of the width.

Here's how I'd start:

```
$('span').each(function(id, value){
  if ($(this).width() > w) {
    largestSpan = id;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
var maxWidth = 0;
var widestSpan = null;
var $element;
$("span").each(function(){
   $element = $(this);
   if($element.width() > maxWidth){
     maxWidth = $element.width();
     widestSpan = $element; 
   }

});
```

Comment: One minute between nearly identical answers. Upvoted for that alone.

Comment: This one is the more elegant and compact of the two. :O

Comment: My only complaint here is that you're creating a new jQuery object every time you're doing `$(this)`. Efficiency really matters in a loop, so it'd be better to store it once. `$element = $(this)` and then reference `$element` instead of `$(this)` every time.

Comment: @AlexKinnee Yes, I agree with this feedback. Updated.

Comment: One more tweak, you could run .width() once and store it instead of running it twice.

Answer (score 5):

Using jQuery to identify widest span in a div:

```
var oSpan;             // Container object for loop item
var oWidest;           // Container object for current widest in loop
var nWidth = 0;        // Int to store current span width
var nWidest = 0;       // Int to contain widest items width
var aWidest = [];      // Array to contain multiple matching spans

// Call each function on spans within div
$('#divContainer span').each(function(nIndex) 
{
    // Set reference to current span to avoid multiple calls per iteration 
    oSpan = $(this);
    // Set current width to avoid multiple calls per iteration
    nSpanWidth = oSpan.width();

    // Compare current width to widest width
    if (nSpanWidth == nWidest)
    {
        // If exact,add to array and set current widest items
        aWidest.push(oSpan);
        oWidest = oSpan;
        nWidest = nSpanWidth;
    }
    else if( nSpanWidth >= nWidest ) 
    {
        // If wider, reset array and set current widest item
        oWidest = oSpan;
        nWidest = nSpanWidth;
        aWidest = [].push(oWidest)
    }
    else { } // Move along short stuff.
});
```